# How to wrap a label

Tags: rendering, materials, uv

[image]

I just bought this asset off turbosquid and I want to wrap a label around it.
The asset can be found here: https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/plastic-jug-lid-gallon-3d-1241344

Do I need to manually UV unwrap this or should it already come UV unwrapped.  How do I go from there also to wrapping a label around it?

Comment: Based on the image, it is already unwrapped. If the label you have is an image texture, select the areas on the model where you want the label to go and give it a material/texture. In the images on the asset page, it shows existing material slots for the label, cap, etc... but I don't know if someone created them just for that example image or if they come with the model. Look in the materials tab, if there are no slots, add one and pick your image.

Comment: the model should be already unwrapped (check this: https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/001241/344/IV/Z.jpg, but in blender it's all overlapped and not usable, I fear). Did you unwrap again manually in blender?

Comment: @Sanbaldo that's a .png file that comes in the zip but when I load into the UV editor its just a background png image.  I dont know how it's used to create an actual UV mapping.  I cam give you the files it came with.  I think maybe it's only for other software like maya